# SQL - Compare multiple row values

Tags: sql, oracle

There are 3 tables. 1.Objects 2.Locations 3.Properties. One object will contain multiple locations and each location will have multiple properties.

```
+--------+------------+   +--------+---------+------------+  +---------+-----------+-----------+-------+
|OBJ_ID  | OBJ_NAME   |   |LOC_ID  | LOC_NAME| OBJ_ID     |  | PROP_ID | PROP_NAME | PROP_VALUE| LOC_ID|
+--------|------------+   +--------|---------+------------+  +---------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| 1      |  BF        |   | 1      |  IND    |   1        |  |   1     | Number    |   6789    |   1   |
| 2      |  GF        |   | 2      |  UAE    |   1        |  |   2     | Name      |   JOHN    |   1   |
+--------+------------+   | 3      |  SLK    |   1        |  |   3     | Date      |   23-09-20|   1   |
                          | 4      |  IND    |   2        |  |   4     | Number    |   6789    |   2   |
                          | 5      |  UAE    |   2        |  |   5     | Name      |   JOHN    |   2   |
                          +--------+---------+------------+  |   6     | Date      |   23-09-20|   2   |
                                                             |   7     | Number    |   1234    |   3   |
                                                             |   8     | Name      |   JOHN    |   3   |
                                                             |   9     | Date      |   23-09-20|   3   |
                                                             |   10    | Number    |   2345    |   4   |
                                                             |   11    | Name      |   JOHN    |   4   |
                                                             |   12    | Date      |   23-09-20|   4   |
                                                             |   12    | Number    |   5678    |   5   |
                                                             |   13    | Name      |   JOHN    |   5   |
                                                             |   14    | Date      |   24-09-20|   5   |
                                                             +---------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

The requirement is that if we pass the specific PROP_NAME to the query, then if that corresponding property is different in any of the Locations associated with in that Object and rest other properties are same then it should print that objects info.

**Example :** If I pass the PROP_NAME = "Number" to the query then it should return the row with OBJ_ID=1 because OBJ_ID = 1 has 3 Locations(LOC_ID = 1,2,3 belong to OBJ_ID = 1 ) and each LOC_ID has 3 properties. In those properties only "Number" is different and rest all other properties are same. So it should return OBJ_ID = 1 details. 
 
**Note :** If you look at OBJ_ID = 2 it has two locations ( Loc_ID=4,5 ) for those location properties along with the Number property Date property value also differs hence it should not be part of output. The requirement was is that if and only if passed PROP_NAME value only differs and rest all other property value are same then only return that object.

Expected O/P for input PROP_NAME = "Number"

```
+--------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
|OBJ_ID  | OBJ_NAME   |LOC_NAME | PROP_NAME | PROP_VALUE |
+--------|------------|---------|-----------|------------+
| 1      |  BF        |  IND    |   Number  |  6789      |
| 1      |  BF        |  UAE    |   Number  |  6789      |
| 1      |  BF        |  SLK    |   Number  |  1234      |
+--------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

My Query tried using self-join but this is not considering whether remaining properties are same or not

```
SELECT
  objects.OBJ_ID,
  loc_tab1.LOC_NAME,
  prop_tab1.PROP_NAME,
  prop_tab1.PROP_VALUE
FROM
  locations loc_tab1,
  locations loc_tab2,
  properties prop_tab1,
  properties prop_tab2,
  objects
WHERE
  objects.OBJ_ID= loc_tab1.OBJ_ID
  AND loc_tab1.OBJ_ID= loc_tab2.OBJ_ID
  AND loc_tab1.LOC_ID = prop_tab1.LOC_ID
  AND loc_tab2.LOC_ID = prop_tab2.LOC_ID
  AND prop_tab1.LOC_ID <> prop_tab2.LOC_ID
  AND prop_tab1.PROP_NAME = 'Number' --Here we can give Name or Date
  AND prop_tab2.PROP_NAME = 'Number' 
  AND prop_tab1.PROP_VALUE<> prop_tab2.PROP_VALUE;
```

Comment: I'd suggest you add a couple of things to your question. 1. Show the expected output of your query based on the sample data you've provided (in a similar table format). 2. Show what you've got so far in working towards a solution.

Comment: @user9601310 Updated expected o/p and my query what I got

Comment: Much better! and look, you then got an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Task description looks pretty strange, but ok, check this:

```sql
with v_join as (
   select
      p.*
     ,l.loc_name
     ,l.obj_id
     ,o.obj_name
   from properties p
        join locations l
             on l.loc_id = p.loc_id
        join objects o
             on o.obj_id = l.obj_id
)
select *
from v_join j1
where 
prop_name = 'Number'
and not exists(
           select 1
           from v_join j2
           where j1.obj_id   = j2.obj_id
             and j1.prop_name != j2.prop_name
           group by prop_name
           having count(distinct prop_value)>1
        )
order by 1,2,3,4,5;
```

Full test case with sample data and results:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ec9064fb67cdb08040836e0a65530cc8

```sql
with
 objects(OBJ_ID, OBJ_NAME) as (
   select 1, 'BF' from dual union all
   select 2, 'GF' from dual
 )
,locations(LOC_ID, LOC_NAME, OBJ_ID) as (
   select 1, 'IND', 1 from dual union all
   select 2, 'UAE', 1 from dual union all
   select 3, 'SLK', 1 from dual union all
   select 4, 'IND', 2 from dual union all
   select 5, 'UAE', 2 from dual
)
,properties(PROP_ID , PROP_NAME , PROP_VALUE, LOC_ID) as(
   select 1 , 'Number', '6789    ', 1 from dual union all
   select 2 , 'Name  ', 'JOHN    ', 1 from dual union all
   select 3 , 'Date  ', '23-09-20', 1 from dual union all
   select 4 , 'Number', '6789    ', 2 from dual union all
   select 5 , 'Name  ', 'JOHN    ', 2 from dual union all
   select 6 , 'Date  ', '23-09-20', 2 from dual union all
   select 7 , 'Number', '1234    ', 3 from dual union all
   select 8 , 'Name  ', 'JOHN    ', 3 from dual union all
   select 9 , 'Date  ', '23-09-20', 3 from dual union all
   select 10, 'Number', '2345    ', 4 from dual union all
   select 11, 'Name  ', 'JOHN    ', 4 from dual union all
   select 12, 'Date  ', '23-09-20', 4 from dual union all
   select 12, 'Number', '5678    ', 5 from dual union all
   select 13, 'Name  ', 'JOHN    ', 5 from dual union all
   select 14, 'Date  ', '24-09-20', 5 from dual
)
,v_join as (
   select
      p.*
     ,l.loc_name
     ,l.obj_id
     ,o.obj_name
   from properties p
        join locations l
             on l.loc_id = p.loc_id
        join objects o
             on o.obj_id = l.obj_id
)
select *
from v_join j1
where 
prop_name = 'Number'
and not exists(
           select 1
           from v_join j2
           where j1.obj_id   = j2.obj_id
             and j1.prop_name != j2.prop_name
           group by prop_name
           having count(distinct prop_value)>1
        )
order by 1,2,3,4,5;
```

Results:

```
   PROP_ID PROP_NAME PROP_VALUE      LOC_ID LOC     OBJ_ID OBJ_NAME
---------- --------- ----------- ---------- --- ---------- ---------
         1 Number    6789                 1 IND          1 BF
         4 Number    6789                 2 UAE          1 BF
         7 Number    1234                 3 SLK          1 BF

3 rows selected.
```

**Update**:
**Optimized version for big data sets**

```sql
with v_join as (
   select
      p.*
     ,l.loc_name
     ,l.obj_id
     ,o.obj_name
   from properties p
        join locations l
             on l.loc_id = p.loc_id
        join objects o
             on o.obj_id = l.obj_id
)
select *
from (
   select 
       j2.*
      ,max(decode(prop_name,'Number',0,cnt_prop_values))over(partition by obj_id) max_cnt_not_number
   from (
      select
         j1.*
        ,count(distinct loc_id) over(partition by obj_id,prop_name) cnt_locations
        ,count(distinct prop_value) over(partition by obj_id,prop_name) cnt_prop_values
      from v_join j1
   ) j2
) j3 
where prop_name='Number'
  and max_cnt_not_number=1
  and cnt_prop_values > 1
```

Full optimized test case with sample data:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b9535c6b56b3a80baed8c8b641ff3c91

```sql
with
 objects(OBJ_ID, OBJ_NAME) as (
   select 1, 'BF' from dual union all
   select 2, 'GF' from dual
 )
,locations(LOC_ID, LOC_NAME, OBJ_ID) as (
   select 1, 'IND', 1 from dual union all
   select 2, 'UAE', 1 from dual union all
   select 3, 'SLK', 1 from dual union all
   select 4, 'IND', 2 from dual union all
   select 5, 'UAE', 2 from dual
)
,properties(PROP_ID , PROP_NAME , PROP_VALUE, LOC_ID) as(
   select 1 , 'Number', '6789    ', 1 from dual union all
   select 2 , 'Name  ', 'JOHN    ', 1 from dual union all
   select 3 , 'Date  ', '23-09-20', 1 from dual union all
   select 4 , 'Number', '6789    ', 2 from dual union all
   select 5 , 'Name  ', 'JOHN    ', 2 from dual union all
   select 6 , 'Date  ', '23-09-20', 2 from dual union all
   select 7 , 'Number', '6789    ', 3 from dual union all
   select 8 , 'Name  ', 'JOHN    ', 3 from dual union all
   select 9 , 'Date  ', '23-09-20', 3 from dual union all
   select 10, 'Number', '1234    ', 4 from dual union all
   select 11, 'Name  ', 'JOHN    ', 4 from dual union all
   select 12, 'Date  ', '23-09-20', 4 from dual union all
   select 12, 'Number', '5678    ', 5 from dual union all
   select 13, 'Name  ', 'JOHN    ', 5 from dual union all
   select 14, 'Date  ', '23-09-20', 5 from dual
)
,v_join as (
   select
      p.*
     ,l.loc_name
     ,l.obj_id
     ,o.obj_name
   from properties p
        join locations l
             on l.loc_id = p.loc_id
        join objects o
             on o.obj_id = l.obj_id
)
select *
from (
   select 
       j2.*
      ,max(decode(prop_name,'Number',0,cnt_prop_values))over(partition by obj_id) max_cnt_not_number
   from (
      select
         j1.*
        ,count(distinct loc_id) over(partition by obj_id,prop_name) cnt_locations
        ,count(distinct prop_value) over(partition by obj_id,prop_name) cnt_prop_values
      from v_join j1
   ) j2
) j3 
where prop_name='Number'
  and max_cnt_not_number=1
  and cnt_prop_values > 1;
```

Comment: "Task description looks pretty strange" - nominated for understatement of the year

Comment: @Sayan Can you provide me an alternative to  not exists because in our db we have close to 10 Million records. so an efficient query is required

Comment: @Sayan I see an incorrect o/p. Look at this example. In this OBJ_ID = 1 rows should not be shown because the Number property value is same across it locations. Only rows with OBJ_ID = 2 rows should be shown because it values differs across the location https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4417c4c2a20d97d34b1ffdef01f6cd77

Comment: @software_guy fixed code with checking distinct values: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b51d2820d22d643c6d119b407d8f5316

Comment: @software_guy and please look at the updated answer "update" section - I've posted optimized version for big data sets. It requires just 1 scan without anti/self joins

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your property values fit into a string, you can use `listagg()` and conditional logic:

```
select o.obj_id, o.obj_name
from properties p join
     locations l
     on l.loc_id = p.loc_id join
     objects o
     on o.obj_id = l.obj_id
group by o.obj_id, o.obj_name
having min(case when prop_name = 'Number' then value end) <> max(case when prop_name = 'Number' then value end) and
       (listagg(case when prop_name <> 'Number' then value end, ',') within group (order by prop_name) =
        listagg(case when prop_name <> 'Number' then value end), ',') within group (order by prop_name)
       );
```

You can use two levels of aggregation rather than `listagg()` as well:

```
select obj_id, obj_name
from (select o.obj_id, o.obj_name,
             (case when min(p.prop_value) = max(p.prop_value) then 1 else 0 end) as is_same
      from properties p join
           locations l
           on l.loc_id = p.loc_id join
           objects o
           on o.obj_id = l.obj_id
      group by o.obj_id, o.obj_name, p.prop_name
     ) op
group by obj_id, obj_name
having min(case when prop_name = 'Number' then is_same end) = 0 and
       max(case when prop_name <> 'Number' then is_same end) = 1;
```

Comment: there is no obj_id and obj_name in properties table I see you are referring group by p.obj_id, p.obj_name

Comment: @software_guy . . . That's fixed.  It was just the wrong table aliases because I added the subquery.

Comment: I still see group by p.obj_id, p.obj_name in the 2nd query and also I need these all these columns OBJ_ID ,OBJ_NAME  ,LOC_NAME,PROP_NAME,PROP_VALUE as a final result

Comment: @software_guy . . . Eventually I'll get the aliases right.